# Listing all compiled kernel modules between two trees?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I've got a system with two different kernel tree sources installed.
One kernel boots perfectly fine, the other kernel panics from not seeing the hdd / label.

How do I compare two different kernel builds and determine which kernel models one has, that the other does not?

So far I've tried `diff` against two scisi module listings.  There's got to be an easier way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options are going to depend on your situation.  Do you have two separate source trees as where the kernels were compiled?  If so, the `.config` file in the top level directory of the source will reflect the configuration.

If I had to guess without enough details, I'd suggest that you may not have selected the appropriate drivers for the disk controllers.

On the kernel that boots, if the necessary options[1] are compiled, you can reference /proc/config.gz.  Unfortunately, this will not help you much as one of the kernels will not boot.  Nevertheless, it could help to compare what is compiled on the working kernel, however, and you could update the broken configuration accordingly.

Certain distributions include the config for the compiled kernel with the package and put it in /boot.

[1] These options:

```
CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
```